# How to publish to a feed if you have offline_access permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, publish

I am trying to publish to a user's FB account, and I have the following permissions:
 * offline_access
 * publish_stream

But when I try to post to the user's account, it appears that FB is asking me for an access token (which I don't have).

Does anyone know the structure of the URL to publish to a FB user's stream when you don't have an access token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do an HTTP POST to /userID/feed?access_token=appID|appSecret

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your app login. About 2/3rds of the way down on the authentication documentation, there are instructions on how to get a session access token for your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Basically, just hit this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials
```

And you will get back an access token you can use to post to any user's wall that your app has permission for.